# Using requests with Pynsist - import error when distributing program

Tags: python-requests, exe, pynsist

Setting the stage:

I have a tkinter program for distribution that does a get request to pull information and then outputs some files in CSV.

Everything works great on the computer that I made it on.  Running it through the .launch file works, executing the .py file inside of pkgs folder words, and installing the app and running it works.

---

The problem:

When I go to distribute the app, the program fails at import requests.  I've made sure and double checked, stripping my program.py file of all requests and executing the app alone with tkinter.  It works great.  Once I add that line in of import requests, despite it having the requests folder in pkgs, it never works.

---

pynsist Installer.cfg:

```
[Application]
name=Program Name
version=1.0
entry_point=program:main

[Python]
version=3.5.1

[Include]
packages = requests
```

My Testing limitations:

I'm working on windows 7 and have only been able to test the distribution on windows 8 and windows 10 computers.  Those are the computers I need to have work however.

Comment: I'll cross link the Github issue where we're debugging this: https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/issues/123

Comment: edit: meant to answer

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!  Included:

```
[Include]
packages = requests
urllib3
chardet
certifi
idna
```

All of which are dependencies for requests.  Once those were included, I was able to run the program perfectly.